# How to find the difference between x and y when they both occur with and without an exponent in this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In this equation:

> $x^2 + y^2 = 64 + 2xy$

Both $x$ and $y$ occur with and without an exponent, but how do I find the **difference** between $x$ and $y$?

If I divide the whole equation by $x$ or $y$, or find the square root of the entire equation, I end up with fractions, or terms with an unsolvable square root, that prevents me from finding the value of $x - y$. So how do I find the value of $x - y$ in a mathematically correct way that deals with the possibility of $\pm$ numbers and fractions?

Comment: Hint: Move the $2xy$ to the other side and try factoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^2 + y^2  =64+2xy \implies x^2 + y^2 - 2xy = (\pm8)^2\quad \color{blue}{\text { (1.)}}$$

Now consider the square of the expression $(x-y) . $

$$(x-y)^2 = (x-y)(x-y) = x^2 -xy -xy +y^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy \quad \color{red}{\text { (2.)}}$$

Now substituting the factorized expression $\color{red}{\text { (2.)}} $ in $ \color{blue}{\text { (1.)}}$

$$ (x-y)^2 = (\pm8)^2 \implies \boxed{x-y = \pm 8 }$$